# How can I switch between two view (created on xib) over the same ViewController (created on storyboard)?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to do something different, mixing XIB and STORYBOARD. My main goal is create a complex STORYBOARD for my application and use XIB to views that are bigger than iPhone screen like the Settings app on iPhone.

As a simple example I created two class view, view1 and view2, using xib interface. Each one do simple tasks, like show many Labels "Hello World - View 1" and "Hello World - View 2" until cover twice the area of a normal  iPhone screen. To do that the view on XIB was set size to "FreeForm" and was placed 6 labels spread along the view. The files .h and .m was written as:

View.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface View1 : UIView {
    UIView *view;

    UILabel *lab1;
    UILabel *lab2;
    UILabel *lab3;
    UILabel *lab4;
    UILabel *lab5;
    UILabel *lab6;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *view;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab1;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab2;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab3;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab4;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab5;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab6;
@end
```

View.m

```
#import "View1.h"

@implementation View1
@synthesize view, lab1, lab2, lab3, lab4, lab5, lab6;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View1" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];    
    [self addSubview:self.view];
}
@end
```

After it, I created a ViewController called myViewController using Storyboard, and put a scrollview inside the view. The code of .h and .m can be saw below:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class View1, View2;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    View1 *viewXIB1;
    View2 *viewXIB2;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;
- (IBAction)changeView1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)changeView2:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "View1.h"
#import "View2.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,755);    
    viewXIB1 = [[View1 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 755)];
    viewXIB2 = [[View2 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 755)];
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:viewXIB1];  
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)changeView1:(id)sender {
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:viewXIB1];
    [self.myScrollView setNeedsLayout];    
    [self.view reloadInputViews];
    [self reloadInputViews];   
}

- (IBAction)changeView2:(id)sender {
    [self.myScrollView addSubview:viewXIB2];
    [self.myScrollView setNeedsLayout];
}
@end
```

The question is that there are no Warning or Errors on the code, but doesn't work.
What's wrong with this code??? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is wrong is that you are never removing none of the views. Replace

the first `IBAction` for

```
- (IBAction)changeView1:(id)sender {
    if (![self.myScrollView.subviews containsObject:viewXIB1]) {
        [viewXIB2 removeFromSuperView];
        [self.myScrollView addSubview:viewXIB1];
        [self.myScrollView setNeedsLayout];    
        [self.view reloadInputViews];
        [self reloadInputViews];
    }
}
```

And analog for the second `IBAction`

```
- (IBAction)changeView2:(id)sender {
    if (![self.myScrollView.subviews containsObject:viewXIB2]) {
        [viewXIB1 removeFromSuperView];
        [self.myScrollView addSubview:viewXIB2];
        [self.myScrollView setNeedsLayout];
    }
}
```

Also, the initialization code of your custom views, should contain something like.-

```
UIView *newView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View1" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:newView];
```

Comment: Well observed @ssantos, but the application still doesn't work. The buttons receiving the Touch and the scrollview too, but there are nothing inside the scrollview. The weird thing is that the instant variable created on View1 and View2 (lab1, lab2 ... lab6) that are the labels looks like not load the content on the XIB, because when I try to see its content using command line: "(lldb) po lab1"return as "$0 = 0x00000000 <nil>". Maybe there are still something wrong.

Comment: It's hard to say what's happening, but looking further into your code, this line doesn't make sense `[self.view addSubview:self.view];`. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Great @ssantos. This was one of two problems that I found, the correct code is [self addSubview:self.view]. The second problem was that I had forget to set the "Class" of the Custom Class for my File's Owner. Now my application work FINE! Thanks a lot, solve my problem.